# Copy stdout contents to a file in command line mode

Tags: linux, c, stdio

I have a program like this. I am in terminal mode. I want to copy the outptu contents to another file. First I tried redirecting, but it didnt work due to buffering. Then i tried unbuffer command. But it didnt work correctly for cases like below

File

```
main()
{
        int i;
        printf("Starting\n");
        scanf("%d",&i);
        printf("The value is %d\n",i);
}
```

Output

```
# ./a.out 
Starting
4
The value is 4
```

Output with **unbuffer** command

```
# unbuffer ./a.out | tee tt
Starting
4


^C
```

Output with simple redirection [works but order of output is not correct]

```
# ./a.out | tee tt
5
Starting
The value is 5
```

I want the contents shown in the screen to be directly copied to a file. I am working in terminal mode [No GUI].

Comment: What do you think about `./a.out > file.txt & ` and after `tail -f file.txt`? ok to read well it is the opposite you cat on the screen what is recorded in the file... but at least you have the identical output. You can use `&` at the end too (`tail -f file.txt &`).

Comment: If i do like that `printf` commands wont command to terminal. They just go to file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unbuffer` [doesn't read from standard input](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/unbuffer1.html) at all by default, so your program just waits without ever getting any input. You can make it read and pass on standard input with the [`-p` option](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/unbuffer1.html):

```
unbuffer -p ./a.out | tee tt
```

will work. The downside is that it doesn't display what you type as you write.

Alternatively, if you control the C program, you can disable the default buffering of standard output when it's not a terminal. You can use, e.g., [setbuf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setbuf):

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
```

or manually flush after each output.

Comment: I am using emacs. Is there any option from emacs

Comment: I'm not sure where emacs fits into the process here - can you be more specific?

Comment: I am using emacs editor. Can anything be done from emacs shell?

Comment: You can run unbuffer -p from the emacs shell (or any shell), or you can run the C program you've modified to disable buffering. Being in emacs or not shouldn't make a difference to any of this.

Comment: The problem with `-p` is that, it wont print user entered data! Any work around?

Comment: Not with unbuffer itself, no. I suppose you can modify the unbuffer script to remove the line: set stty_init "-echo"